# Siteground detects malware in SimpleCaptchaClass.php file

Tags: php, cpanel, captcha, malware, malware-detection

Siteground detects the following as suspicious PHP file. Can you please assist on how to resolve

[image]

```
Source code - https://pastebin.com/pzbhRyWu
```

Comment: Please post whole message and no screenshots. Also pastebin URL is invalid.
Its probably because it calls `eval`